# Matplotlib slider won't move

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider, spyder, azure-databricks

I'm trying to use sliders for dynamically change parameters on a graph but the sliders won't move. I can't make it to work neither on Azure-Databricks nor on Spyder. I'm using this code here:

```
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
 
# Create subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.35)
 
# Create and plot sine wave
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
s = 5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 3 * t)
l, = plt.plot(t, s)
 
# Create axes for frequency and amplitude sliders
axfreq = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
axamplitude = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
 
# Create a slider from 0.0 to 20.0 in axes axfreq
# with 3 as initial value
freq = Slider(axfreq, 'Frequency', 0.0, 20.0, 3)
 
# Create a slider from 0.0 to 10.0 in axes axfreq
# with 5 as initial value and valsteps of 1.0
amplitude = Slider(axamplitude, 'Amplitude', 0.0,
                   10.0, 5, valstep=1.0)
 
# Create function to be called when slider value is changed
 
def update(val):
    f = freq.val
    a = amplitude.val
    l.set_ydata(a*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t))
    
# Call update function when slider value is changed
freq.on_changed(update)
amplitude.on_changed(update)
 
# display graph
plt.show()
```

Am I missing something?

Versions:
matplotlib: 3.5.1
python: 3.9.12
Spyder version: 5.1.5 None
Python version: 3.9.12 64-bit
Qt version: 5.9.7
PyQt5 version: 5.9.2
Operating System: Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

This is quite old, I noticed that the question is common, but only found the answer after a lot of googling.

Try to add the following below import numpy:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

To display the graph change as follows:

```
plt.show(block=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are only 4 types of widgets available in Azure Databricks as follows:

•   `text`: Input a value in a text box.

•   `dropdown`: Select a value from a list of provided values.

•   `combobox`: Combination of text and dropdown. Select a value from a provided list or input one in the text box.

•   `multiselect`: Select one or more values from a list of provided values.

After referring this [documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html) I tried to use `interact`

But It gives output as shown in below image.

[image]

---

**Update -**

To make it work you need to have Databricks Runtime version 11.0 and above as given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/widgets)

Then you can utilize `ipywidgets`

Now below sample code will work.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

widgets.IntSlider(
    value=7,
    min=0,
    max=10,
    step=1,
    description='Test:',
    disabled=False,
    continuous_update=False,
    orientation='horizontal',
    readout=True,
    readout_format='d'
)
```

Reference - https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/7.7.0/examples/Widget%20List.html